# ASP.NET Image uploading from URL

Tags: asp.net, image, file-upload

I have an aspx page,where the user will enter a valid image url(ex : https://stackoverflow.com/Content/Img/stackoverflow-logo-250.png).
I need the program to upload this image to the Server.
How can i do this  ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
System.Net.WebClient webClient = new WebClient();

webClient.DownloadFile(@"http://stackoverflow.com/Content/Img/stackoverflow-logo-250.png",
@"c:\path\localfile.png");
```

You can use [Server.MapPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524632.aspx) to get physical directory on the server corresponding  to the relative or virtual path, for example `Server.MapPath("~/Images")`

Comment: Can I ask why you put @ at the beginning of the URL & Filename?

Comment: @leen30 for escaping \ characters