# how to upload live images without saving

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a live URL I want to download images without saving it. I also want to upload an image to another live URL. I want to code this using thread or socket programing.
How do I save image file from one server to another server without saving it to local?

Comment: what do you mean with without saving ... where you dont want to save?

Comment: He means save it from one server to another

Comment: See  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/256526/asp-net-image-uploading-from-url
  and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5596747/download-stream-file-from-url-asp-net

Comment: Must be more clear what you ask, with a sample of what you have try. Now the question is too fuzzy.

Answer (score 1):

Download to a MemoryStream, rewind the stream, and upload the stream's content to the second site.  See http://odetocode.com/Blogs/scott/archive/2004/10/05/webrequest-and-binary-data.aspx

Answer (score 0):

This would definitely helps u,

```
byte[] imgcontent;
                //Convert live images into byte array to pass it for ftp server
                HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
                WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();

                Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream();
```